# How can I find the number of lines that contain a certain word in java using Java Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

My method would read from a text file and find the word "the" inside of each line and count how many lines contain the word. My method does work but the issue is that I need only lines that contain the word by itself, not a substring of the word as well

For example, I wouldn't want "therefore" even though it contains "the" it's not by itself.

I'm trying to find a way to limit the lines to those that contain "the" and have the length of the word be exactly 3 but I'm unable to do that.

Here is my method right now:

```
public static long findThe(String filename) {
    long count = 0;
    
    try {
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename));
         count = lines.filter(w->w.contains("the"))
                .count();
        
        } 
    catch (IOException x)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("File: " + filename + " not found");
    }

    
    System.out.println(count);
    return count;
}
```

For example, if a text file contains these lines:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
This is the fourth line
Therefore, this is a name.
```

The method would return 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use regex to enforce *word boundaries*:

```
count = lines.filter(w -> w.matches("(?i).*\\bthe\\b.*")).count();
```

or for the general case:

```
count = lines.filter(w -> w.matches("(?i).*\\b" + search + "\\b.*")).count();
```

Details:

- `\b` means "word boundary"
- `(?i)` means "ignore case"

Using word boundaries prevents `"Therefore"` matching.

Note that in java, unlike many other languages, `String#matches()` must match the *entire* string (not just find a match *within* the string) to return `true`, hence the `.*` at either end of the regex.

Answer (score 3):

### Update:

[Thanks to Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281766/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-lines-that-contain-a-certain-word-in-java-using-jav/65281812#comment115431882_65281812) for the following valuable recommendations:

> Better: `filter(Pattern.compile("\\bthe\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).asPredicate())`, avoiding to repeat the work
> of `Pattern.compile(…)` for every line.

and

> When posting a complete solution, I’d also incorporate
> [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html),
> even when the OP did not (or especially as the OP did not).

**Updated method definition:**

```
public static long findThe(String filename) {
    long count = 0;
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
        count = lines.filter(Pattern.compile("\\bthe\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).asPredicate()).count();
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.out.println("File: " + filename + " not found");
    }
    return count;
}
```

### Original answer:

Replace

```
w->w.contains("the")
```

with

```
w->Pattern.compile("\\bthe\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(w).find()
```

The `\b` is used for [word boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Comment: This is the same as my solution, it seems to count the instances where "the" is inside another word.

Comment: @timtommy - Please try this. The `\b` is used for [word boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) and it should work.

Comment: Better: `filter(Pattern.compile("\\bthe\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).asPredicate())`, avoiding to repeat the work of `Pattern.compile(…)` for every line.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger for this yet another important suggestion. I've incorporated it as well in the answer.